# Postfix TLS Error - Permission Denied

Tags: postfix

I have a weird problem. In Postfix I am having trouble with some new certificates. I have a .crt and .key file and when trying to use them in main.cf I get this in logs:

```
Sep 16 08:06:09 mx1 postfix/smtpd[25172]: warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file /etc/postfix/new.crt: disabling TLS support
Sep 16 08:06:09 mx1 postfix/smtpd[25172]: warning: TLS library problem: 25172:error:0200100D:system library:fopen:Permission denied:bss_file.c:402:fopen('/etc/postfix/new.crt','r'):
```

The weird thing is, the old certificates work fine and the permissions seem identical:

```
-rw-rw-r--.  1 root       root        2774 Sep 15  2018 old.crt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root        1675 Sep 15  2018 old.key
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root        2228 Sep 16 07:51 new.crt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root       root        1675 Sep 16 07:52 new.key
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Run `ls -Z` on those files. Most probably they have the wrong selinux context.

Comment: Ahh yes that was it! I changed them to match the old and its working now, thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

The `.` at the end of the permissions (`-rw-r--r--.`) denotes that there are extended SELinux permissions on the files that are not shown by a normal `ls -l`.

Run `ls -Z` on those files. Most probably they have the wrong SELinux context.

You can then set the correct SELinux context using `chcon`.

Comment: It happens when you move instead of copy files. You can use `mv -Z` to have the context reset as part of the move, which prevents the problem. You can also copy the file then delete the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run

```
restorecon -rv [directory]
```

to restore the correct SELinux context, if you moved the directory from somewhere else, or without the -Z flag.

Make sure the permissions and ownership are correct (640 & root:root) on the directory, not just the files inside.

In my case, I did an sftp put to get the certs onto the server, then I had copied the entire directory including the certificates to the final location.

Make sure that when you correct the permission and ownership (root:root & 640), that you do it to the entire directory, recursively, not just the files inside the directory.